# Expected number of leaves at a certain level of a "grown" binary tree

Tags: trees

Let's say that we have a binary, not necessarily complete, tree. This tree is the result of a "duplication process" of an initial node (root).

So initially we start with a single node (the root) that has these duplication probabilities:

```
P[0] = "probability of not duplicating/becoming a leaf"
P[1] = "probability for the current node of having only one child"
P[2] = "probability for the current node of having two children" = P[0] - P[1]
```

According to these probabilities we let the tree grow until a certain stopping condition is met.

My question is: assuming we want to collect every node at a certain level `l` (possibly not the deepest one) and count how many of those nodes are leaves. How many leaves should I expect to count?

My answer would be that, in general, I would expect a number of leaves equal (on average) to `P[0]*N_l`, where `N_l` is the total number of nodes at level `l`.

Am I correct?

Comment: The event that a node is a leaf at level $l$ requires not only that that node is a leaf, but also that all its ancestors were not leaves.

Comment: @Hellen Of course. How does this help me?

Comment: It answers "Am I correct?" with a "no".

Comment: @Hellen I don't understand. Why?